# Querying MongoDB array in Python returns not matched parts

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Having this simplified document:

```
{
   "_id" : "test_id",
   "name" : "customname",
   "timestamp" : "2010-10-10 10:00:01",
   "customarray" : [
       {
           "my_id" : 1,
           "value": 23
       },
       {
           "my_id" : 2,
           "value": 16
       }
   ]
}
```

I want to return just the `customarray.value` part for those documents which `customarray.my_id = 1`

This is my approach using pymongo:

```
res = [res for res in col.find({"customarray.my_id": 1}, {"customarray.value"})]
```

But I get this output:

```
{'_id': 'test_id', 'customarray': [{'value': 23}, {'value': 16}]}
```

When my desired output is:

```
{'_id': 'test_id', 'customarray': [{'value': 23}]}
```

How can I get only the desited value of the array? I dont want to get the second value (`value = 16`, which is `my_id = 2`)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of the `$elemMatch` operator inside the projection block and apply your filter conditions there instead.

```
res = [res for res in col.find({"customarray.my_id": 1}, { "name": 1, "customarray": { "$elemMatch": { "my_id": 1 } } })]
```

Comment: You just have to include that key name in the projection block. I have updated the alnswer.

Comment: It seems that this is not working as expected. This solution only applies the filter, but returns all the documents: If I have nother documents in the same collection (with another structure), the query always returns ALL the documents of the collection with the filter applied. I think this is because the first field is `{}` and it returns all the documents.

Comment: Edited answer with original condition {"customarray.my_id": 1} - it's waiting for approval. Downside - id must be provided twice - both in filter and project.

Comment: @poleszcz thanks for the edit, totally forgot about find part

Answer (score 0):

You can try this aggregation query:

- `$unwind` to deconstruct the array.
- `$match` to get values you want.
- `$project` to get the desired output.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$customarray"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "customarray.my_id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "value": "$customarray.value"
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OgnLkwv0mJw)